# Open browser tabs to execute robot framework test case

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a doubt regarding RobotFramework(RF) so posting this to Stackoverflow , I have to test 4 website using RF , and each run parallely at the same time using pabot . So i reached out to a point where i want same session cookies to be used for all the 4 websites , but in RF code that i wrote each time when the test case ends it closes the browser so clearing session cookie , So my concern is that , is there any way i can test all this 4 website in same browser with same session cookie and ran in  different tabs at the same time  .

or in short Is there any way i can use same session cookie for all the 4 test suites running parallelly

Comment: I have posted an answer, did you manage to try it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [Suite Setup and a Suite Teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown). In the Suite Setup open the browser, in the Suite Teardown close the browser. In between the two run your four test cases for the four different websites in the same session sequentially.

Here is what I mean:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Suite Setup       Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Firefox     
Suite Teardown    Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Test Website 1
    Go To     https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Log    Do test with same session cookies.

Test Website 2
    Go To     https://meta.stackexchange.com/
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Log    Do test with same session cookies.

Test Website 3
    Go To     https://gardening.stackexchange.com/
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Log    Do test with same session cookies.

Test Website 4
    Go To     https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Log    Do test with same session cookies.
```